# Android layout_height to wrap smallest child

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-custom-view

As part of a larger project, I'm attempting to create a custom image gallery which will hold images from the web. I have no control over their size and their layout (order, total number [up to ten], and number per row [up to three]) is defined by the API I'm working with. I'm using nested LinearLayouts to build the loose grid programmatically but this is an XML proof of concept...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:divider="@drawable/photoset_vert_divider"
    android:showDividers="middle">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:divider="@drawable/photoset_horz_divider"
        android:showDividers="middle">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/tall" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/tall" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/wide" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is 60% of what I'm looking for and gets me

[image]

…but this is my target:

[image]

What I want is a `android:layout_height="wrap_smallest_content"` sort of thing that scales all the ImageViews to the correct size and then crops them all down to match the "shortest" child.

Comment: try to replace this android:scaleType="centerCrop" to android:scaleType="fitXY" ....

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you're going to eventually do this programmatically, you could always just subclass LinearLayout to find the smallest height of the containing ImageViews as they load and then set that as the layout's height. Then all you'd have to do with the images is set their height to `match_parent`.

Answer (score 0):

It's really better to set the fixed layout_height to inner **LinearLayout**. You can just do this in XML

If you're focusing on variety of devices then give a **id** to the  inner **LinearLayout** then set the LinearLayout size dynamically by measuring the screen size of the device. To measure the screen size programmatically

By using the DisplayMetrics you can get height and width of the screen of any device.
here is the code.

```
DisplayMetrics metrics; 
int width = 0, height = 0;
```

In your onCreate Method

```
 metrics = new DisplayMetrics();        
 getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);


 xheight = metrics.heightPixels;        
 xwidth = metrics.widthPixels;
```

Try this to get the Screen height.

Then set the inner **LinearLayout** programmatically like this

```
linearLayout.getLayoutParams().height = xheight - 50;
```

Depending upon the *xheight* change the - 50 value

the your xml will change to something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:divider="@drawable/photoset_vert_divider"
    android:showDividers="middle">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:divider="@drawable/photoset_horz_divider"
        android:showDividers="middle">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/tall" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/tall" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/wide" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```